# Conceal subscripts in Coq syntax

Tags: syntax-highlighting, conceal

### Some context and setup

I've been using [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr) lately and the excellent [coqtail](https://github.com/whonore/Coqtail) plugin for syntax and proof development. I've seen some folks using Proof General in Emacs for a similar environment, and it conceals numbered subscripts, with

```
x0
```

turning into

```
x₀
```

Nifty, says I, and implements it in Vim:

```
" ~/.vim/after/syntax/coq/bk_extras.vim
for [digit, subscript] in [
      \ [0, '₀'],
      \ [1, '₁'],
      \ [2, '₂'],
      \ [3, '₃'],
      \ [4, '₄'],
      \ [5, '₅'],
      \ [6, '₆'],
      \ [7, '₇'],
      \ [8, '₈'],
      \ [9, '₉']]
  execute printf('syntax match coqSubscript /\%(\k\+\)\@<=%d\>/ containedin=ALLBUT,.*Comment,coqRequire conceal cchar=%s', digit, subscript)
endfor
```

And I source this code in `~/.vim/after/syntax/coq{,-{goals,info}}.vim` with

```
runtime! syntax/coq/bk_extras.vim
```

---

### The problem

There are a few, but they are pretty interrelated so I'll put them together. (If people object, I can split the questions out.)

- Numbers like `10` end up like `1₀`, which makes sense based on the syntax pattern but not semantically. Is there a way to not match when the subscript is preceded by a number?
- Sometimes (and I can't figure out when) the subscripts don't conceal. That is, sometimes `x0` will show as `x₀` and others just `x0`. Example:

[image: Interactive Coq session with some x0 concealed to x₀ and others not]

Is there a way to get all of them (and the `H0`s, etc.) to work? They seem to not conceal most often when the are followed by a (space or not) colon, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim syntax is a beast. It takes some time to get used to it.

I suggest to try this:

```
scriptencoding utf-8

syn match coqSubscript keepend /\K\d\+/ms=s+1 transparent contains=coqSubscriptDigit
    \ containedin=ALLBUT,coqComment,coqRequire,coqSubscript,coqSubscriptDigit
syn match coqSubscriptDigit /0/ contained conceal cchar=₀
syn match coqSubscriptDigit /1/ contained conceal cchar=₁
syn match coqSubscriptDigit /2/ contained conceal cchar=₂
syn match coqSubscriptDigit /3/ contained conceal cchar=₃
syn match coqSubscriptDigit /4/ contained conceal cchar=₄
syn match coqSubscriptDigit /5/ contained conceal cchar=₅
syn match coqSubscriptDigit /6/ contained conceal cchar=₆
syn match coqSubscriptDigit /7/ contained conceal cchar=₇
syn match coqSubscriptDigit /8/ contained conceal cchar=₈
syn match coqSubscriptDigit /9/ contained conceal cchar=₉
```

UPD. Subscripts will not be shown within `coq-goals` syntax, `coq-hypothesis` region. The reason is the region start is defined with `matchgroup=coqIdent`. From `:h :syn-matchgroup`:

> In a start or end pattern that is highlighted with "matchgroup" **the
> contained items of the region are not used**.  This can be used to avoid
> that a contained item matches in the start or end pattern match.

Comment: Would this turn all digits into subscripts? Neat. I'll have to try it.

Comment: This fixes the number issue, but doesn't help with the colons, where in the screenshot `H0 :` and `x0 :` do not conceal (the `coq-goals` pane, but in other places too).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Not sure which one. But you should anyway check what is the syntax item underneath. Maybe it's that "coqRequire" you've excluded for some reason.

Comment: No, it's `coqIdent` that seems to be the issue, but that's not excluded

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Updated. This is an issue with original syntax file.

Comment: Ah, sad. Thanks for digging into this.